# fish shell + omf + git plugin: how to customize the prompt in the terminal

Tags: fish, omf

I have fish shell with omf  with agnoster theme and git-plugin installed.

I would like to tune my prompt a bit. Does anyone here know where/how I do that. I ran fish_config; but that did not show my current prompt properly. So I am reluctant to go that route. I would rather do it by typing it in; but can't figure out where the final prompt is being stored. I tried 'echo $fish_prompt'. Did not help.

Would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`fish_prompt` is a function. See https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/fish_prompt.html. To see where it is defined run `functions --details fish_prompt`. There is no "final prompt [is] being stored" as I understand that phrase. There is a function that creates the prompt. Your `echo $fish_prompt` would only output something useful if the prompt was a literal string (which isn't supported). You can use `functions --all fish_prompt` to see where it is defined and the content of the function.

When I used Fish I did not use OMF (I'm now an Elvish user). I had a custom function defined in *~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish*. So I can't explain how to customize the OMF "agnoster" theme prompt. You'll need to read the documentation for that theme to learn what knobs, if any, it provides for customizing its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: edit **function fish_prompt** in file: **.local/share/omf/themes/agnoster/functions/fish_prompt.fish**.

Explanation:

- This exact file may not work in cases with different plugin's and/or different theme.
- The way I figured this was to search for all "*prompt.fish" functions in my home directory.  Put a distinct print statement with the prompt in each one of them and check which one got printed and modified the fish_prompt.fish function in that file - which is working for me!